# error creating a makefile for python project

Tags: python, makefile, autoconf, automake

I am trying to figure out how to create makefile for a python based project (secondly this is the only programming language I am most familiar with), so far I followed [this tutorial](http://www.micahcarrick.com/tutorials/autotools-tutorial-python-gtk/getting-started.html) to get started. However when it came to generate `configure.ac`, this file is empty and so is `configure` file.

Also when I ran `aclocal`, I didn't get `aclocal.m4` as described, but I got `aclocal.cache` directory.

In the end, when I tried to run `automake --add-missing`, I got the following error messages:

```
$ automake --add-missing
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
automake: error: no 'Makefile.am' found for any configure output
automake: Did you forget AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile]) in configure.ac?
```

Now, I am confused what is wrong and what to do. Secondly, I also discovered on [hitchhiker's guide to packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html)

Is the description of hitchhiker's guide enough? Is any better than `make` technique ?

Comment: Python projects are currently usually built with `distutils` (standard library) or [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (a somewhat enhanced version of distutils) and not `make`.

Comment: I need help with make !

Comment: There's probably no reason to use autotools instead of distutils/setuptools for python projects. I recommend you follow that hitchhiker's guide or http://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/introduction.html

Comment: Why do you need a makefile in the first place? And which Python implementation are you using — CPython, IronPython, Jython, or perhaps another implementation? Answering these two questions will give people who reply a better idea of how to help. Overall, the idea is that Python shouldn't need a build file. distutils should provide everything you need. A makefile typically builds something, whereas a Python script executes something. This is why it doesn't seem to make sense that you need a makefile.

Comment: I am using `python 2.7.4`, if `makefile` builds something than doesn't `make install` does the same thing as `setup.py install` ? I want for a user to be able to `git clone` my project and just run `make install` to install it on his machine!

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz did you find any solutions to this??

Comment: @DaveR no I started using setuptools